# How can one listen to a method's completion in Air for Android application

Tags: android, actionscript-3

I am working on a little android app [Air for Android],and I am struggling on how to listen a method's completion.

### I wrote some code like this:

```
//these code are written in MXML file
var oauthConnection:OauthConnection = new OauthConnection();
busyOn();
init();
busyOff();
```

which init() is a function that I wrote in a class named OauthConnection,
saved as file named [OauthConnection.as]
My problem is when init() is still executing though, busyOff() got executed.
what i should do to make sure busyOff() is executed after init() is done.
Someboy,Anybody, if you have a clue,help me! thanks!

Comment: I'm a little confused, the functions `busyOn()`, `init()` and `busyOff()`, are they methods of `OauthConnection`? And why are there breaks(`<br>`) in you code? I thought I knew the answer to your question but cwallenpoole's answer is starting to make me think I've misunderstood it.

Comment: sorry, that was my first post on this site, and i wanted to use <br> do the break line,sorry for that! anyway,thanks to  cwallenpoole, my problem got solved! sorry for the cufusing!

Comment: I've learned and I've delete the <br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this would be done with the Event structure of ActionScript (this is an incredibly simple example):

```
// in OauthConnection.init as the last line
dispatchEvent( new Event( "eventName" ) );

//around your example aboe.
oauthConnection.addEventListener( "eventName", eventHandler );
busyOn();
init();

// later in the class.
function eventHandler( evt:Event ):void
{
    busyOff();
}
```